# How much space does an array occupy?

Tags: java, arrays

If I create 10 integers and an integer array of 10, will there be any difference in total space occupied?

I have to create a boolean array of millions of records, so I want to understand how much space will be taken by array itself.

Comment: Yes, an array is an object, so it has more than just the values. The array will take more space.

Comment: Might be, but is it worth your time thinking about this?

Comment: Look at this http://java.dzone.com/articles/java-how-much-memory-do

Comment: well i want to know, if i am creating a boolean array of millions of records, how much space will be taken by array

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An array of integers is represented as block of memory to hold the integers, and an object header.  The object header typically takes 3 32bit words for a 32 bit JVM, but this is platform dependent.  (The header contains some flag bits, a reference to a class descriptor, space for primitive lock information, and the length of the actual array.  Plus padding.)

So an array of 10 ints probably takes in the region of `13 * 4` bytes.

In the case on an `Integer[]`, each Integer object has a 2 word header and a 1 word field containing the actual value.  And you also need to add in padding, and 1 word (or 1 to 2 words on a 64-bit JVM) for the reference.  That is typically 5 words or 20 bytes per element of the array ... unless some Integer objects appear in multiple places in the array.

---

Notes:

1. The number of words actually used for a reference on a 64 bit JVM depends on whether "compressed oops" are used.
2. On some JVMs, heap nodes are allocated in multiples of 16 bytes ... which inflates space usage (e.g. the padding mentioned above).
3. If you take the identity hashcode of an object and it survives the next garbage collection, its size gets inflated by at least 4 bytes to cache the hashcode value.
4. These numbers are all version and vendor specific, in addition to the sources of variability enumerated above.

Comment: Plus you need four (or eight on 64 bit JVM) for each of the pointers to these objects.

Comment: @Thilo Actually it's not easy to predict pointer size. Due to alignment the JVM can still get away with 4-byte pointers. That's what I'm observing at my system.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik: That's great! I worried about that a bit back, and when I checked back then, the answers I got was that pointers do need 8 bytes, unless you enable some extra compression option. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3733215/memory-requirements-of-an-object-reference-on-a-64-bit-jvm  Glad to see that is fixed now (it seemed a bit excessive).

Comment: @Thil0 - I already included that ... *"and one word for the reference"*.

Answer (score 4):

Some rough lower bounds calculations:

Each int takes up four bytes.  = 40 bytes for ten

An int array takes up four bytes for each component plus four bytes to store the length plus another four bytes to store the reference to it. = 48 bytes (+ maybe some padding to align all objects at 8 byte boundaries)

An Integer takes up at least 8 bytes, plus the another four bytes to store the reference to it. = at least 120 for ten

An Integer array takes up at least the 120 bytes for the ten Integers plus four bytes for the length, and then maybe some padding for alignment. Plus four bytes to store the reference to it. (@Marko reports that he even measured about 28 bytes per slot, so that would be 280 bytes for an array of ten).

Comment: On 64bit Java, all pointers take eight bytes instead of four, making the difference between primitive and wrapper even bigger.

Comment: I measured, an `Integer[]` full of Integer instances occupies 28 bytes per slot on average (64-bit JVM). A fun fact is that it is exactly the same as an array of `Object`s.

Answer (score 2):

In java you have both Integer and int. Supposing you are referring to int , an array of ints is considered an object and objects have metadata so an array of 10 ints will occupy more than 10 int variables

Answer (score 2):

In light of your comment it will not make much difference if you used an array. Array will use a negligible amount of memory for its functionality itself. All other memory will be used by the stored objects.

EDIT: What you need to understand is that the difference between Boolean wrapper and boolean primitive type. Wrapper types will usually take up more space than the primitives. So for missions of records try to go with the primitives.

Another thing to keep in mind when dealing of missions of record as you said is Java Autoboxing. The performance hit can be significant if you unintentionally use this in a function that traverses the whole array.

Comment: The difference can be quite big, though, if it is `Integer[]` vs `int[]`. In this case, the wrapper objects would take up most of the space.

Comment: Agreed. Answer edited. But the Array semantics will take the same memory I think. Major difference comes from the objects/elements stored in the array. SO i don't think I was that off the mark.

Comment: The wrapper type argument is good, but *not so much for Boolean*, because there are only two possible values, so there will be a lot pointer sharing. Of course, you still need to store four (or eight) bytes for the reference, instead of "just" one for the bool.

Comment: Yes not so much but still enough to make a difference in huge number of records..

Answer (score 2):

What you can do is **measure**:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  final long startMem = measure();
  final boolean[] bs = new boolean[1000000];
  System.out.println(measure() - startMem);
  bs.hashCode();
}
private static long measure() {
  final Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
  rt.gc();
  try { Thread.sleep(20); } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
  rt.gc();
  return rt.totalMemory() - rt.freeMemory();
}
```

Of course, this goes with the standard disclaimer: `gc()` has no particular guarantees, so repeat several times to see if you are getting consistent results. On my machine the answer is one byte per `boolean`.

Comment: If I wanted to measure, I'd use jmap and look at the heap memory dump.

Comment: @Thilo If you had an already running system that would be your best option, but in this case it's just extra work digging through the dump.

Comment: @Thilo I already have a lot of experience with this method and the accuracy is great.

Comment: @Thilo For completeness I've just checked the dump appproach. It reported 64 MB occupancy when adding the reported allocation sizes, yet 56MB total heap is taken. The diff is that it reported 8 bytes/slot in an Object array, where in fact it's 4 bytes/slot. I'm definitely sticking with my approach :-)

Answer (score 1):

It needn't reflect poorly on the teacher / interviewer.

How much you care about the size and alignment of variables in memory depends on how performant you need your code to be. It matters a lot if your software processes transactions (EFT / stock market) for example.

The size, alignment, and packing of your variables in memory can influence CPU cache hits/misses, which can influence the performance of your code by up to a factor of 100.

It's not a bad thing to know what's happening at a low level, as long as you use performance boosting tricks responsibly.

For example, I came to this thread because I needed to know the answer to exactly this question, so that I can size my arrays of primitives to fill an integer multiple of CPU cache lines because I need the code that is performing calculations over those arrays of primitives to execute quickly because I have a finite window in which I need my calculations to be ready for the consumer of the result.

Answer (score 0):

In terms of RAM space, there is no real difference

Comment: Wrong answer. Check the comments and the other answers.

Comment: +1 there is a high relative difference, but unless you do this *alot* it will make no real difference to your application.

Answer (score 0):

If you use an array you have 11 Objects, 10 integers and the array, plus Arrays have other metadata inside. So using an array will take more memory space.

Now for real. This kind of question actually comes up in job interviews and exams, and that shows you what kind of interviewer or teacher you have... with so many layers of abstraction working down there in the VM and in the OS itself, what is the point on thinking on this stuff? Micro-optimizing memory...!

Comment: It could only be 1 object if it is a primitive `int[]` (the question is a bit unclear to that point)

Answer (score 0):

> I mean if i create 10 integers and integer array of 10, will there be
>   any difference in total space occupied.

```
(integer array of 10) = (10 integers) + 1 integer
```

The last "+1 integer" is for index of array ( arrays can hold 2,147,483,647 amount of data, which is an integer). That means when you declare an array, say:

```
int[] nums = new int[10];
```

you actually reserve 11 int space from memory. 10 for array elements and +1 for array itself.