# Caliper : JVM throws OutOfMemoryError Exception

Tags: java, jvm, caliper

I am using google caliper to run a very simple benchmark on a method. I am getting the following exception.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at com.code4refernce.caliper.SimpleCaliperTest.timeStringLen(SimpleCaliperTest.java:24)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor2.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    at com.google.caliper.SimpleBenchmark$1.run(SimpleBenchmark.java:125)
    at com.google.caliper.TimeMeasurer.measureReps(TimeMeasurer.java:174)
    at com.google.caliper.TimeMeasurer.warmUp(TimeMeasurer.java:62)
    at com.google.caliper.TimeMeasurer.run(TimeMeasurer.java:122)
    at com.google.caliper.InProcessRunner.run(InProcessRunner.java:74)
    at com.google.caliper.InProcessRunner.run(InProcessRunner.java:49)
    at com.google.caliper.InProcessRunner.main(InProcessRunner.java:103)
```

I don't understand why I am getting this exception. I tried to increase the JVM memory then also I get this exception.

The benchmark code is as following.

```
package com.code4refernce.caliper;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

import com.google.caliper.Param;
import com.google.caliper.SimpleBenchmark;

public class SimpleCaliperTest extends SimpleBenchmark {
    String regex = "(\\d{3}-\\d{3}-\\d{4})|(\\d{10})";
    Pattern REGEX_PATTERN = Pattern.compile(regex);

    String mdn[];
    Random random;
    @Param
    int index;

    @Override 
    protected void setUp() {
         random = new Random(0);
        mdn = new String[4];
            mdn[0] = "098412sdfasdf8000";
            mdn[1] = "11345";
            mdn[2] = "1423567890";
            mdn[3] = "123-456-7890";
    }


    public Boolean[] timeStringLen(int reps){
        Boolean results[] = new Boolean[reps];

        for(int i = 0; i<reps; i ++){

            results [i]= mdnCheckRegularMethod(mdn[index]);
        }
        return results;
    }
    public Boolean[] timeRegex(int reps){
        Boolean results[] = new Boolean[reps];
        for(int i = 0; i<reps; i ++){

            results[i]=mdnCheckRegEx(mdn[index]);
        }
        return results;
    }
    private boolean mdnCheckRegularMethod(String mdn){
        boolean result = false;

        if(mdn.length()==10){
            try{
                Integer.parseInt(mdn);
                result = true;
            }catch(Exception e){
                result = false;
            }
        }
        else if(mdn.length() == 13){
            byte[] bmdn = mdn.getBytes();
            for(int i = 0; i<bmdn.length; i++){
                if((i == 3 || i == 6) && bmdn[i] == '-'){}
                else if(bmdn[i] >= '0' && bmdn[i]<='9'){}
                else{
                    result = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        else{
            result = false;
        }
        return result;
    }

    private boolean mdnCheckRegEx(String mdn){
        return REGEX_PATTERN.matcher(mdn).matches();
    }
}
```

and the main class which runs the caliper benchmark.

```
package com.code4refernce.caliper;
import com.google.caliper.Runner;

    public class CaliperRunner {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            String myargs[] = new String[2];
            myargs[0] = new String("-Dindex=0,1,2,3");
            myargs[1] = new String("-Jmemory=-Xms1024m ");
            Runner.main(SimpleCaliperTest.class, myargs);
        }
    }
```

I don't understand whats going wrong here. Can someone point out?

Comment: Which one is line 24? The Boolean array or the call to mdnCheckRegularMethod?

Comment: Boolean[] results = new Boolean[reps]; \\line24

Comment: What if you use the native `boolean` type for array initialization?

Comment: I tried it and worked. thanks. But couldn't get the reason behind this behavior.

Comment: The `Boolean` array creates the number of `reps` null references to the Boolean type (approx 8 byte per reference). Whereas as the primitive alternative just allocates space required for the primitive type, see e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3733215/memory-requirements-of-an-object-reference-on-a-64-bit-jvm. In other words, it might fail again in the future as it depends on the size of `reps`. (I'm not familar with caliper).

Comment: Does your benchmark write to System.out ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method `timeStringLen(int reps)` may be called with `reps` up to `Integer.MAX_VALUE`. You could give your VM more memory via the `-Xmx` switch, but you'd better not allocate needlessly big arrays, as it's not needed at all:

```
public boolean timeStringLen(int reps){
    boolean result = false;

    for(int i = 0; i<reps; i ++){
        result ^= mdnCheckRegularMethod(mdn[index]);
    }
    return result;
}
```

This does the same job, the only reason for returning a value is to prevent the JIT from optimizing it all away. Xoring is enough here, counting the cases when the method returned true is another possibility.

---

But there's most probably another problem with your benchmark: The high values of `reps` used show that it's running faster then I'd expect. The result of each iteration seems to be the same and I'd guess that you loops gets optimized to something like

```
result[i] = Boolean.TRUE
```

which I don't think you want to measure. Using something like

```
Random random = new Random(0);
mdn = new String[4][1<<16];
for (int i=0; i<mdn.length; ++i) {
    mdn[0][i] = String.format("%03ddsfasdf00000", random.nextInt(1000));
    mdn[1][i] = String.format("%04d", random.nextInt(10000));
    mdn[2][i] = String.format("%10d", random.nextInt((int) 1e10));
    mdn[3][i] = String.format("%03d-%03d-%03d", random.nextInt(1000), random.nextInt(1000), random.nextInt(1000));
}
```

would help.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I edited the code(check out the first post in this thread). I don't know why regular expression is not performing that well. Is something wrong here?

Comment: @Rakesh You'd better have created a new question, as the original one has been answered. The title doesn't match anymore. I'd copy the text into a new question and rollback the changes here.